# Sencha Touch XML Reader Problem

Tags: xml, sencha-touch, extjs

I am student and cannot afford the premium support, so my question here:

I have quite a simple XML and it gives me the following Error:
http://img33.imageshack.us/i/screenprn.png/

```
Ext.regModel('User', {
  fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
});

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
  model: 'User',
  autoLoad:true,
  proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   url : 'ajax/user.xml',
   reader: {
    type : 'xml',
    model: 'User',
    record: 'user'
   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, your XML sould be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Ed Spencer</name>
        <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Abe Elias</name>
        <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
    <user>
</users>
```

Else it won't be an XML ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need a root-tag in a xml-file?

Comment: Hi @XmlNoob, and welcome to StackOverflow.  One of the other moderators must have thought you were posting a question instead of an answer.  We get many, many posts like that, so it isn't always easy to put a lot of time into evaluating each one.  I have restored your answer.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in XML!!!!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Ed Spencer</name>
        <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Abe Elias</name>
        <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
    <user> <--- </user>
</users>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way

proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: ''}),