# Sencha Touch loading XML data in List give a Javascript TypeError

Tags: javascript, listview, xml-parsing, sencha-touch, typeerror

I am new to Sencha Touch framework. I need to load some data from an XML file into a `List`. Right now I am just trying to make the [XMLReader example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlReader) given in the documentation work.

When I try to run the below mentioned code, I get an error message:

```
Javascript error on Line 7212 
sencha-touch-debug.js
TypeError: Result of expression 'records' [undefined] is not an object.
```

**Code - index.js:**

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function(){
        
        Ext.regModel('User1', {
            fields: ['id', 'name','email']
        });
        
        var temp = new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'User',
            autoLoad:true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'users.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'user'
                }
            }
        });
        
        var list = new Ext.List({
            fullscreen: true,
            itemTpl : '{id} {name}',
            store: temp
        });
        list.show();
    }
});
```

**users.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
  <user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Ed Spencer</name>
    <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
  </user>
  <user>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Abe Elias</name>
      <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
  </user>
</users>
```

I know its a very small thing that I am missing, but I'm not sure what it is. I tried the [solution mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013591/sencha-touch-xml-reader-problem), but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dit notice you didn't define the root node of the xml file.

```
var temp = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'User',
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'user',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure if this is the only thing, try it out and let me know!

Comment: Hi Aidan... Your solution solved the issue. Thanks a lot for the replying. I actually figured that out sometime after posting the question. I guess I should have closed my question for others... Still thanks a lot.